# Default url in route.config to be put as a url of an action method in area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I want the default action method to be called in `route.config` should be the action method of an `area`. So I have done something like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

    routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "LocationCon", action = "LocationIndex",  id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    namespaces: new[] { "Locator.Areas.LocationArea.Controllers" }
                ); 
}
```

Here - `LocationIndex` is the action name, `LocationCon` is the controller and `LocationArea` as area.
This is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it needs to be works fine, Please comment other routes and check I think url will map to another route, also you can add `defaults: { area = 'LocationArea', ... }` instead of namespaces, However it is good to add namespace to resolve the conflict between same controller name.

Comment: @Prasad: This is the only route that I have in `route.config`. It hits the action method and executes successfully but when returns `No resource found`.

Comment: check you have view with the same name of action (if different name add like this `return View("<viewName>")`). When we said `return View()` it will check at **Areas/LocationArea/Views/<ControllerNameFolder>/**, **/View/<AllFolders of controller>**, **/Views/Shared/**  I think at return time resource is not present at these location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `No resource found` error originated from MVC view engine, where your view engine still using default parameters to find proper cshtml file even action methods executed successfully.

AFAIK, by default MVC view engine searching view files in `Project/Views/ControllerName` and `Project/Views/Shared` directory, which your `Project/Culture/ControllerName` doesn't included.

You can configure custom view engine to search corresponding view files like example below:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class ViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public ViewEngine()
    {
            MasterLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                 // your layout cshtml files here
            };

            ViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                 // your view cshtml files here. {0} = action name, {1} = controller name
                 // example:
                 "~/Culture/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
            };
            PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;

            FileExtensions = new[]
            {
                "cshtml"
            };
    }
}
```

Hence, on `Global.asax` file place your custom view engine on `Application_Start` method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
      AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
      ...
      // other code here
      ...
      ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ViewEngine()); // add your custom view engine above
}
```

CMIIW.

Comment: Yes you are right. It was searching with culture as well. Thanks :)